# Responsive div cuts of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a div with text with rounded corners, of which the right side contains an image (with rounded corners aswell). As this text will be hooked up to a CMS, the content could be changed someday. This is why I want the div to be responsive: become as high as the text. and cut off the rest of the image without losing the rounded corner or shrinking the image.

I have included the code down below, I really hope someone can help me!

```css
.spacing {
  padding: 15px;
}

.banners {
  display: block;
}

.banner_home {
  min-height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.banner_home_text {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner_home_text p {
  margin: 15px;
}

.banner_home .banner_home_text img {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="banners">
  <div class="spacing">
    <div class="banner_home col-xs-12">
      <div class="banner_home_text">

        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x375" alt="Barbecue">

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac lorem eget tellus volutpat pellentesque ut eu libero. Proin et dui ut nibh laoreet varius. Praesent nec dignissim ex. Mauris pharetra convallis lacus, a rhoncus urna porttitor id. Morbi
          vel tellus id quam condimentum egestas. Phasellus elementum molestie lacus. Donec aliquam congue mollis. Sed pellentesque orci tellus, sed fringilla turpis ullamcorper dapibus.
        </p>

        <p>
          Duis commodo egestas lacus quis commodo. Duis semper dapibus mi, posuere dictum libero fermentum sed. Etiam ligula eros, ornare nec mattis at, rhoncus vel ante. Vestibulum eget finibus nisl. Nam ullamcorper scelerisque sem non sagittis. Pellentesque habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, when you say 'cut off the rest of the image' - do you mean that when it's wide, and the text is only on a few lines, you want the box to keep up to the bottom of the text, and hide the image bottom, so that it's the same width, but cropped?   Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comment above is correct, how about this? 
The image is absolutely positioned, so it can hide and not push the div down...

```css
.spacing {
  padding: 15px;
}

.banners {
  display: block;
}

.banner_home {
  min-height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.banner_home_text {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:375px;
}

.banner_home_text p {
  margin: 15px;
}

.banner_home .banner_home_text img {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: block;
  width:375px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="banners">
  <div class="spacing">
    <div class="banner_home col-xs-12">
      <div class="banner_home_text">

        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x375" alt="Barbecue">

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac lorem eget tellus volutpat pellentesque ut eu libero. Proin et dui ut nibh laoreet varius. Praesent nec dignissim ex. Mauris pharetra convallis lacus, a rhoncus urna porttitor id. Morbi
          vel tellus id quam condimentum egestas. Phasellus elementum molestie lacus. Donec aliquam congue mollis. Sed pellentesque orci tellus, sed fringilla turpis ullamcorper dapibus.
        </p>

        <p>
          Duis commodo egestas lacus quis commodo. Duis semper dapibus mi, posuere dictum libero fermentum sed. Etiam ligula eros, ornare nec mattis at, rhoncus vel ante. Vestibulum eget finibus nisl. Nam ullamcorper scelerisque sem non sagittis. Pellentesque habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .banners {   
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="banners">   
        <img src="http://placehold.it/375x375" alt="Barbecue" class="img-responsive">

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac lorem eget tellus volutpat pellentesque ut eu libero. Proin et dui ut nibh laoreet varius. Praesent nec dignissim ex. Mauris pharetra convallis lacus, a rhoncus urna porttitor id. Morbi
          vel tellus id quam condimentum egestas. Phasellus elementum molestie lacus. Donec aliquam congue mollis. Sed pellentesque orci tellus, sed fringilla turpis ullamcorper dapibus.
        </p>

        <p>
          Duis commodo egestas lacus quis commodo. Duis semper dapibus mi, posuere dictum libero fermentum sed. Etiam ligula eros, ornare nec mattis at, rhoncus vel ante. Vestibulum eget finibus nisl. Nam ullamcorper scelerisque sem non sagittis. Pellentesque habitant
          morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>

      </div>
```

You need to add a overflow hack here.